# Retrieve past deployments

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

Is there any way (using Metadata API or other options) to retrieve all successful deployments to an org from the past, say, 6 months?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to see? There's some stuff available, but not much.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ideally, which components were deployed per each and every deployment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Salesforce does not differentiate between what was changed through Metadata API or directly through Setup. They are all listed the same in the Setup Audit Trail. But, anyone who has used the Setup Audit Trail knows that it is not the easiest to wade through.

If you use the Metadata API retrieve properly (break up your Org metadata into chunks and stitch them back together), you can fetch the state of the Org  and then diff to figure out what was changed and when it happened. There are paid release management products (including our own product, Snapshot) that keep track of deployments that went through them to give you a timeline and a searchable index of the list of changes that touched a particular metadata etc. Not sure if helps you or not.

Disclaimer: I am part of the Metazoa team, the maker of Snapshot.